# integral in influxDB: unit parameter

Tags: influxdb

I have data from *Solcast*
[image]

I want to `integrate` to find, for each day, the area underneath the daily peak in order to produce an estimate for daile generation.

This is what I've come up with:

```
import "date"

solcast = from(bucket: "solar")
  |> range(start: date.add(d: 1d, to: today()), stop: date.add(d: 2d, to: today())) // tomorrow
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "solcast"and r["_field"] == "forecast")
  |> window(every: 1d)
  |> integral(interpolate: "linear", unit: 1d)
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
    _time: date.truncate(t: r._start, unit: 1d),
    _value: r._value,
  }))

  solcast |> yield()
```

The `window` splits the data into one table for each day upon which the `integral` should work. However, omitting the `unit` parameter from `integral` increases the value of the result by a factor of about 500,000!
What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

It is never explicitly stated in the docs but it looks like the default value of the `unit` parameter of `integral` is `1s`.
When you omit it influx is doing a linear fill to create a datapoint every second and then calculating the area under the curve in seconds.

The result is therefore 86400 times bigger (60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours).